# RESTful API PUT/PATCH to flip boolean

Tags: api, rest, boolean, endpoint

What is the proper way to flip a boolean over a RESTful API?

Consider, for example, a `users/toggle_middle_name` endpoint. By default, each user would not have his or her middle name displayed, unless they opted in by hitting an endpoint.

Obviously, this would not be a `GET` endpoint, as you'd be writing information to the database. But, in a `PATCH/PUT` request, it's my general understanding that one should send parameters, signifying what data is being set to. So, for example, one would send `{show_middle_name: true}`. But since this is just a boolean being flipped server-side, ideally, you wouldn't need to know whether to send `true` or `false` prior to the call. Just hit the endpoint, and it flips from one to the other, without a value being sent.

The question then becomes, is it okay to just hit a `PUT`/`PATCH` endpoint *without* parameters, and simply return the result in a response? Or are parameter-less `PUT`/`PATCH` API calls discouraged? Why or why not?

Comment: The disadvantage of just being a toggle is that your server has no confirmation of the correct outcome. If you drop one request, suddenly the toggle is doing the *exact opposite* of what the user intends (and maybe the exact opposite in the database of what the front end is telling them is happening). If you send the result you want after the operation is completed, that's unambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply said: Don't

In my opinion there should be no specialized resource for flipping a boolean because a boolean in itself does not define a self contained entity.

Instead I would make this an attribute of `User` and do a `PATCH` on `/users/john_doe` with

```
{
  "show_middle_name": true/false
}
```

As the [comment from jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666198/restful-api-put-patch-to-flip-boolean/37667363#comment62810763_37666198) applies.

Comment: Would you still recommend this approach if there was a business rule on the server that didn't allow one of the 2 values of the boolean to be set? Say for example, there was a `payment` entity with an `approved` field: it would start as `false` (when the resource is created) and then be updated to `true` at some point, but once approved, it could never go back to `false` again. Would you keep the PATCH and return an error (like bad request) explaining the value can only be set to `true`, or would you go with a custom method in this case like `POST /payments/{id}/approve`?

Comment: Yes, even with underlying business rules my choice would still be the simple property instead of an endpoint to flip.

BUT your scenario can also be modeled as an `payments/{id}/approval` resource that may only be created but never deleted. This would also allow to store meta data such as date of approval or approver.

For me this is the difference between a modeled resource and a "method invocation".

Comment: That's actually a very insightful point with the `approval` resource. It does model the requirement In a far better way indeed.